# Hibernate aliasToBean with field collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have next entities:

```
public class Photo {
   Long id;
   String url;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
   User user;
   // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

And second:

```
public class User {
   Long id;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   private Collection<Photo> photos;
   // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

DTO:

```
public class UserDTO {
    Long id;
    List<String> photosUrls;
}
```

And HQL query:

```
 select u.id, p.url from User as u inner join u.photos as p
    where u.id = :id
```

In result i want my UserDTO object, which i will use in rest(json).
But my query like this throws exceptions, with error:

> HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while
>   calling setter for property [com.dto.UserDTO.photosUrls (expected
>   type = java.util.List)]; target = [com.dto.UserDTO@7650a5f3], property
>   value = [some url]

I can't find right solution to get result objects list like:

```
List<UserDTO> result;
```

I read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363152/hibernate-aliastobean-with-collection), but my result of List will contain dublicates of users id and unique photo url.

```
user_id     url
   1       http1
   1       http2
   3       http3
   3       http4
```

---

This question more explained that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821554/hibernate-hql-criteria-result-contains-collection). And, also, there are no right answer.

Comment: It looks like there's some ambiguity with UserDTO: your code has `photosUrls` but the error references `pictureUrls`.

Comment: @ErikGillespie sorry, really my problem is more complex) it's example, which solve my problem